# Did Hitler actually say "Millionen stehen hinter mir."?

Tags: hitler, quotes

There is a [fairly famous poster](https://www.sfmoma.org/artwork/91.139/) made by [John Heartfield](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Heartfield) in 1932 depicting Adolf Hitler with the quote "Millionen stehen hinter mir.", which is a pun that might be roughly translated as "the millions follow me". Along with the picture it is meant to say that the "millionen" was money provided by the "fat cats" like the one behind him in the picture. Meaning aside, my question is, did Hitler actually say at some time "Millionen stehen hinter mir."? I have to believe that he did actually say this but I have not been able to find confirmation.

Comment: John Heartfield montage was published (16 October 1932) by the [A.I.Z. (Arbeiter-Illustrierte-Zeitung)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbeiter-Illustrierte-Zeitung), that was on the opposite end of the political spectrum during an excessive political period. This not a quote, but a political claim made by a opposition party.

Comment: German language lecture that goes deeper into this question: (*"Millions stand behind me" - myths about the financing of the NSDAP and Hitler's way to power*) ["Millionen stehen hinter mir" – Mythen über die Finanzierung der NSDAP und Hitlers Weg zur Macht • Weiterbildungszentrum • Freie Universität Berlin](https://ssl2.cms.fu-berlin.de/fu-berlin/sites/weiterbildung/PM_gasthoerercard/Ringvorlesungen/Geschichte-als-Waffe/Video-7/index.html)

Comment: November 13th, 1931, "und heute mit 42 Jahren stehen Millionen hinter mir". But not sure how reliable this is, just found it on google

Comment: @Jan Are trying to improve the question or trying answer it? IMO: the proper next tstep is to improve the question? And only that in this comment space?

Comment: @LangLangC: Neither. I do not really think "found on the Internet" is good enough for an answer. OTOH it might be a lead to an actual answer.

Comment: @Jan Had you posted the link to the text of the speech, then maybe. I couldn't find it. Only this reference for that date. [Rede Adolf Hitlers in der Darmstädter Festhalle, 13. November 1931](https://www.lagis-hessen.de/de/subjects/xsrec/current/9/sn/edb?q=YToxOntzOjY6InBlcnNvbiI7czoyMzoiMTE4NTUxNjU1OkhpdGxlciwgQWRvbGYiO30=). Since in the previous election (14th of September 1930) they received over 6 million votes, the statement is plausible.

Comment: Here is a somewhat acceptable link, i believe. The quote is towards the end of his speech: https://archive.org/details/HitlerRedenSchriftenAnordnungenFebruar1925BisJanuar193312Bande/page/n3865/mode/2up

Comment: archive.org also offers a full text version which is nice for searching. If you look for "hinter mir", you find a few similar sentences, but none where John Heartfield's pun works so well.

Comment: I'd still like to see preliminary research - have you searched for this Hitler quote? What do standard reference sources say?  I don't think the question should be re-opened until it addresses all the issues raised in comments (at which point the comments should be flagged for deletion)

Comment: The motto of John Heartfield montage, published 1932-10-16, ('Millionen stehen hinter mir') does not turn up in the 5172 page collection of Hitler speeches between 1925-01 and 1933-01. The nearest match ('Millionen Menschen hinter mir stehen') is found twice in the [1932-05-25 speech](https://archive.org/details/HitlerRedenSchriftenAnordnungenFebruar1925BisJanuar193312Bande/page/n4472/mode/2up). This is possibly the base from which the (politicaly adapted) 'motto' was based upon.

Comment: The tranlated quote in full: *Not that 13 **million people are behind me**, but it is my great pride to be able to say that 13 **million people stand behind me**, who are united in one idea, that it was possible to bridge seemingly insurmountable opposites and people of all classes,  of all professions, ages, creeds, etc. to bring together and unify into one great creed.* The 13 million comes from the previous presidential election result.

Comment: Given the fact that these words were uttered during the [depression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Depression), billions, rather than [mere millions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Depression_in_Central_Europe), would probably have been a far better choice of words, insofar money is concerned, unless he was purposefully trying to make a fool of himself.

Comment: @Lucian Germany's hyper-inflation was in 1923, not in 1931.

Comment: @Lucian And, as your link states, the depression started October 1929, allmost 6 years after the hyper inflation ended.

Answer (score 11):

On November 13th, 1931, Hitler said in Darmstadt (emphasis mine):

> Mit 25 Jahren bin ich ins Feld, mit 31 kam ich zurück, und heute, mit 42 Jahren **stehen Millionen hinter mir**.

> At the age of 25, I joined the war, at the age of 31, I returned, and today, at the age of 42, millions support me.

[source](https://archive.org/details/HitlerRedenSchriftenAnordnungenFebruar1925BisJanuar193312Bande/page/n3869/mode/2up)

Obviously Hitler's words were supposed to refer to millions of people, while Heartfield makes it appear as if they refer to millions of Marks, or the owners of millions of Marks (i.e. factory owners etc). This is, of course, a classic technique in political caricature and applied reasonably transparently here.

If you search the full-text version of that source for "hinter mir", you will find several similar phrases, but less ambigous re. who or what these millions are. "Millionen Menschen", "13 Millionen", "eine Millionenbewegung" etc.

Comment: Congratulations in finding this source. The cross-referencing inside the collection will make it easier to find out who said what when.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, he did say something **similar**, but in a different context.

As Jan has found in the speech of 13th of November 1931 (page 3870), these statements were made with the goal to differentiate their goals from that of the other main parties.

In the speech quoted below, made shortly before a [local state parliament election](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oldenburgischer_Landtag#Landtagswahl_1932), he goes into great detail how the other parties have failed in the previous 13 years but also his rejection of *Socialism* as the second main idea (*Nationalism* being the first). The final goal is that only one should prevail:

> Kein Volk aber kann zwei Ideen zu gleicher Zeit dienen.
>
> > But no people can serve two ideas at the same time.

His speeches often then end with the conclusion that their idea is gaining more support after each election. This is the context of the **million[s of] people stand behind me** statements. Such reoccurring statements can therefore be considered a 'Motto'.

[image]

The motto used in John Heartfield montage, published 1932-10-16, ('Millionen stehen hinter mir') does not turn up in the 5172 page collection of Hitler speeches between 1925-01 and 1933-01. The nearest match ('Millionen Menschen hinter mir stehen') is found twice in the [1932-05-25 speech](https://archive.org/details/HitlerRedenSchriftenAnordnungenFebruar1925BisJanuar193312Bande/page/n4472/mode/2up).

> Nicht daß 13 **Millionen Menschen hinter mir stehen**, sondern das ist mein größer Stolz, sagen zu können, daß 13 **Millionen Menschen hinter mir stehen**, die in einer Idee geeint sind, daß es möglich war, scheinbar unüberwindbare Gegensätze zu überbrücken und Menschen aller Stände, aller Berufe, Lebensalter, Bekenntnisse usw. zusammenzuführen und zu einigen in einem großen Glaubensbekenntnis.
>
> > Not that 13 **million people are behind me**, but it is my great pride to be able to say that 13 **million people stand behind me**, who are united in one idea, that it was possible to bridge seemingly insurmountable opposites and people of all classes,  of all professions, ages, creeds, etc. to bring together and unify into one great creed.

The 13 million comes from the previous presidential election result that took place on the 10th of April 1932.

This is possibly the base from which the (politicaly adapted) 'motto' was based upon.

---

**Sources**:

- [Hitler Reden, Schriften, Anordnungen, Februar 1925 Bis Januar 1933 (12 Bände)](https://archive.org/details/HitlerRedenSchriftenAnordnungenFebruar1925BisJanuar193312Bande/page/n4472/mode/2up) (PDF)

  - page 4468: speech of 1932-05-25

    - page 4472 quote
- ["Millionen stehen hinter mir" – Mythen über die Finanzierung der NSDAP und Hitlers Weg zur Macht • Weiterbildungszentrum • Freie Universität Berlin](https://ssl2.cms.fu-berlin.de/fu-berlin/sites/weiterbildung/PM_gasthoerercard/Ringvorlesungen/Geschichte-als-Waffe/Video-7/index.html)
- [A.I.Z. (Arbeiter-Illustrierte-Zeitung)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbeiter-Illustrierte-Zeitung)